# How to show the resque worker status to the end user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, background-process, resque

I'm using Resque in my application to run background jobs. The background jobs are taking a considerable amount of time to complete and thats why I want to display the status of the jobs to the end user so that they know by when the tasks will be completed. I am having a difficult time to find a solution to this problem, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) gem?  The gem will give you a hash that you can query for the status of the job.  Next, you'll need to figure out the best way to notify the user.

Personally, I think the most straight forward method would be to just send an email when the job is complete.  If you desire to notify the user in their web browser, you'll probably need to implement some sort of pub/sub system that fires off a notification to alert the browser.  This is reasonably complicated, so just sending an email is probably your best option.